# How do I reload a single element in html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a html which has some textboxes and a list. I then added paging for my list but whenever I try to click on the next page for list, it reloads the entire page which then results to an error because the page requires an id that becomes null when the paging is cliked. How do I resolve this? I'm using MVC and razor(cshtml).

Answer (score 0):

provide required id in url so that you can get it on other page

for eg.

http:://localhost/abc.html?id=xyz

Comment: I already have that but what happens is that when I click on the next page, it reloads the entire page while only retrieving the values for the second page of the list so the id that it's looking for becomes 0.

Comment: then you have to pass as many information as needed on other page in url. this is a very common process whether by get or post or in session watever is suitable in your case